# In Artifactory Pro, is there a URL for the latest snapshot version of an artifact on any release?

Tags: artifactory

I want to get out the latest artifact from the repository, irrespective of what version number it is on.

e.g.  If I have 2 artifacts in the repository like so:

1.0-SNAPSHOT
1.1-SNAPSHOT

I would like a URL that allows me to get out the 1.1-SNAPSHOT version.

According to the documentation, (http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveLatestArtifact) this is possible with release versions by adding [RELEASE] into the GET URL where the version number should be.

I'm not sure how I would do this equivalently with snapshots.

(NB.  Maven supports this feature through LATEST and RELEASE version indicators, but I am using wget at this point)

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, as the documentation states, "Integration and release tokens cannot be mixed together".
Feature request is welcomed.

Comment: what is an integration token?

Answer (score 0):

I think this feature was implemented since you asked the question. The documentation page you linked now includes SNAPSHOTs as well:

> Download the latest Maven unique snapshot artifact:
>
> `GET
>   http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/0.9.9-SNAPSHOT/logback-classic-0.9.9-SNAPSHOT.jar`